# Retrieve Logged in User in API Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-nova

I have a controller which handles API calls. The user might have different roles. According to his role(s) he might access parts of the API or not.

**Middleware**

```php
class CheckUserRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, string $role)
    {
        if(\Auth::check()) {
           :
        }
    }
}
```

Although I call the API with a logged in user, I get null. In the `$request` param I neither have the user. What do I do wrong?

Comment: How do you authenticate your users?

Comment: First of all, think about Gates, instead of middleware, since it's gates' responsibility to check for access. I assume you are not authenticating the users properly and that is why you can't fetch the user. Please share more details about the authentication process

Comment: The API routes don't start sessions... Look in the \App\Kernel.php file you will see that the Api middleware group does not have the start session... You could try adding the StartSession::class to it and replace your middleware in your api routes from 'auth:api' to just 'auth' ... solution in these areas... Now why not just use web routes for those session based calls? APIs are typically session less and authorize through a token... (take a look at Passport... ). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As some of you mentioned, api call does not start a session, I guess it is in order to avoid CSRF attacks.

One solution is to use [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport):

> Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes.

Another solution, maybe more vulnerable (but in my case good enough), is to start session on api call. For this you need to modify `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

And add to `'api'` entry the following middleware:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

(I took this solution from [this brief article](https://rosswintle.uk/2018/01/laravel-simple-cookie-auth-simple-apis/))